# where is the repository remote URL stored?

Tags: git

Where is the git repository URL for remote is stored ?

the one that I get when I execute this : `git config --get remote.origin.url`

So the below command would set different for each repo by itself ?

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://newhost.com/usr/local/gitroot/myproject.git
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All repo configuration would be inside `/project-root/.git/config` file